# HighCharts-XRange Series: how to restrict data labels width to stay within corresponding data point width

Tags: highcharts

I am working with XRange charts in High Charts where I have custom data labels for my data points. I face a similar problem in 2 scenarios:

1. When data label text is longer than width of corresponding data point range, it overflows outside and onto adjacent data points and hides their label, like this:

[image: like so]

2. When scrolling across the x-axis, the data labels slide across and overflow even when the data point range isn't wide enough to show. This looks quite confusing;

[image: like so].

You would notice it looks even worse here;

[image: here].

How do I fix this so that the data labels never flow outside the extent of the data point?

I have tried tweaking the "inside" parameter but it only ensures that the label doesn't flow into an adjacent row. Similarly, I looked at the crop and overflow options in the API but couldn't get it to work for me as needed.

I understand the width option in style might let me address the first problem, but I can't have a common absolute value in pixels for all labels as the width of each is dynamic. Also, the second problem still wouldn't be solved.

You can find both issues re-created here : https://jsfiddle.net/td0bsxg1/4/ . I need to handle both of them as gracefully as possible.

Do I need to change some parameter for the data labels?

```
dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            defer: false,
            inside: true,
            formatter: function () {
              return 'Too Long Data Label';
            }
        }
```

Comment: Could you attach the code you use to generate your current chart? Without a [mcve] it is more tedious for people to help you.

Comment: Apologies for having missed it. Re-created both issues with sample data and included link to JS Fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can dynamically set individual **width** style for each data label and define rules for them:

```
events: {
  render: function() {
    if (redrawEnabled) {
      var points = this.series[0].points,
        chart = this,
        dataLabelWidth,
        width;

      redrawEnabled = false;

      Highcharts.each(points, function(point) {
        width = point.shapeArgs.width;

        if (width < 20) {
          point.dataLabel.hide();
        } else {
          point.dataLabel.show();
        }

        point.dataLabel.css({
          width: width
        });
      });

      chart.series[0].isDirty = true;
      chart.redraw();

      redrawEnabled = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/wo0q9nzr/

Comment: I am not sure if I should create a separate question for this, but is a similar 'height' parameter supported for Data Labels? When I set the width dynamically and if the text is too long, it overflows above and below the data point and even to the adjacent row. I would prefer to handle it more gracefully and have it within the data point bar, perhaps even truncate it if needed.

Comment: Hi slimshady927, yes I think that should work. Please test `height` option and if it will not work please provide me with some minimal live example.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work as expected for me, as you'll notice here: https://jsfiddle.net/b0j2fkqg/ . If you scroll a bit to the left, you will notice the label on the red data point overflowing down as well. Essentially, I need to contain the labels to always stay within their data points and I am open to any approach for that.

Comment: Hi, yes I can see the problem, but unfortunately you can not set `height` for SVG text element. I think that you could try to use `useHTML` option: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.xrange.dataLabels.useHTML